# Laplace Tracnsform. Can we write solution without limit A approaches infinity?

Tags: differential-equations

Laplace Tracnsform. Can we write solution without limit A approaches infinity? Like: Integral from 0 to infinity and then functions without limit and A->infinity ?

Comment: You probably do not need any limits, you only need the correspondence tables. If that is not the case, take your question to math.stackexchange.com. Or post some code with a minimal working example demonstrating your problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about calculus (integration theory) and thus belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com